# Azure ServiceBus TimeoutException after SDK upgrade

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We have recently upgraded to the latest version of the ServiceBus SDK and we started to get TimeoutExceptions during SendAsync queue operations.

This only happens from the servers that only have Send to the queue (no receive), the servers that listen don't exhibit this problem.

We re-use the Queue client (as a singleton within the process) 
When you restart the process, it starts to work properly but then less than an hour later all our SendAsync calls throw TimeoutException

This problem doesn't happen with SDK v 4.1.3, but happens with both 4.1.5 and 4.1.6, so something  definitely broken starting 4.1.5

Anyone else having this issue? Anything specific we should be doing to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: I've run into this behavior when I created a new QueueClient for every message that I sent. Since QueueClient negotiates a new connection to the Service Bus queue with each new instance, it can exhaust the number of available connections, resulting in the same Throttling problems you're describing. I know you're re-using a QueueClient so this doesn't apply to you, but I do want to add this comment for anyone else who experiences similar issues.

Comment: yeah thanks, definitely re-using the client. I think there is some sort of heart beat or something that gets invoked with the receiver, but not the sender. (In the release notes for 4.1.5 they talk about heartbeat). Did your problem happen with releases prior to 4.1.5?